# What's the perfect (or maximum) resolution of attachment image for iOS notifications?

Tags: ios

As described in the question, I don't know what's the perfect or maximum resolution of attachment image for iOS notifications.

Comment: I don't think it would be a problem to display. But the extension has to download the image once the notification arrives. When we use large sized image it may cause delay. Try to keep ratio.

Comment: Apple defines the size of the attachment in bytes only: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationattachment